# How to get polymorphic relationship type while eager loading in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship, polymorphic-relationship

While querying polymorphic relationship existence or absence, Laravel Eloquent provides `whereHasMorph` and `whereDoesntHaveMorph` methods which really helpful to create queries related to the types. But what about for eager loads?

Here is the situation:

Think about 3 models **App\Photos**, **App\Videos** and **App\Blogs**.

These three models are all feedable which means they have a polymorphic relationship with **App\Feed** model.

But while **App\Photos** and **App\Videos** models are reactable (have a polymorphic relationship with **App\Reactions** model), **App\Blogs** model doesn't have this relationship.

Let's check out the methods:

**App\Feed**

```
public function feedable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**App\Reactions**

```
public function reactable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**App\Photos**

```
public function feed() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Feed', 'feedable');
}

public function reactions() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Reactions', 'reactable');
}
```

**App\Videos**

```
public function feed() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Feed', 'feedable');
}

public function reactions() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Reactions', 'reactable');
}
```

**App\Blogs**

```
public function feed() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Feed', 'feedable');
}
```

While querying feeds from **App\Feed** model, I also want to get reactions count. But because of that **App\Blogs** model doesn't have a method named `reactions`, this query causes errors.

How can I create query like this:

```
$feeds = Feed::with([
    'feedable' => function($query) {
        // I need to get the feedable_type of the feedable here.
        // module_exists is a custom helper to check if an module is installed and active
        if ($type != 'App\Blogs' && module_exists('Reactions')) {
            $query->withCount('reactions');
        }
    }
])->all();
```

**Edit**

I have tried to simplify my question but I think I need to provide more information about the application.

The application is a content management system (social network system) that third party developers can develop modules for. Blogs, Photos, Videos, Feed, Reactions, Comments, Share etc. are all different modules and they can be disabled or removed by the site owners. So while developers are creating modules, they have to take into consideration that Reactions, Coments etc modules can be disabled or removed.

Answer (score 1):

1- Naming conventions in Laravel states that models are singular form, so you may consider renaming the models to `Photo` and `Video` etc..

2- In your case, the `Blog` model doesn't have reactions, so you may create a `type` Scope in the `Feed` model like:

```
public function scopeHasReactions($query)
{
    return $query->whereIn('reactable_type', ['App\Photo', 'App\Video']);
}
```

3- use `$withCount` property to get counts, in `Photo` model in example:

```
protected $withCount = ['reactions'];
```

Finally you can make a query like this:

```
$feeds = Feed::hasReactions()->get();

$feeds->first()->reactions_count;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just updated my question according to your answer. Please check it again. 1. Different modules can have Photo, Video etc models. 2. All of the feeds whether they are reactable or not will be displayed. So I want to get not only reactable ones but also the unreactables. 3. If site owner disables or removes Reactions module, this will cause error.

Comment: You can think about adding a reactions_count property to the Blog model with the value of zero and hide it in the view.